# writing "int mid" outside of while loop doesn't give output, and if written inside of while gives me output, I don't understand the reason

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

My code implements a basic binary search in a 1D array. Writing `mid` inside of while scope is giving the output. What I don't understand is when I declared start, end also outside of while loop which gives output without issue.

```java
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {1,23,34,45,56,67,78,88};
        int target = 78;
        int result = BinarySearch(arr, target);
        System.out.println("Element found at index : " + result);

    }

    static int BinarySearch(int arr[], int target){
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.length - 1;
        // **writing mid here not giving any error, not even output**
        int mid = start + (end - start) /2;
        while(start <= end){
            int mid = start + (end - start) /2; // **If mid written here, it gives the output**
            if(target < arr[mid]){
                end = mid - 1;
            } else if(target > arr[mid]){
                start = mid + 1;
            }else{
                we got the value (if its present.)
                return mid;
            }
        }
        // **if while didnt run (that means value not present in the array).**
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are shadowing the `int mid` that you declare before the loop.  Only declare it once.

Comment: No actually I was just showing that writing mid outside of while doesn't give the output, I should have commented one declaration

Comment: @MustkimKhatik for a better answer, please share the code which is giving error

Comment: You do not need to declare `mid` outside the loop then.  Every iteration of the loop will result in a new value for `mid` hence changing the flow of your program

Comment: `mid` is a **value**, not an **expression** that is evaluated each time you access it. So if you put it outside the loop, it is only calculated once and then doesn't change, which is not how a binary search algorithm is supposed to work.

Comment: ohhh, I got it, start and end are changing just once, while mid is changing in every iteration, Thank you for clearing my doubt!

Answer (score 0):

When it's outside the loop it is only evaluated for the first run of the loop, then never again. It is not updated, so `target > arr[mid]` is just always true and the loop always chooses that path, running in circles forever.

But really, you should get a debugger up and running and try stepping your code, before asking someone for help. It's the best teaching tool, since it shows, not tells.